# Apply animation to text inside a list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to apply animation to text inside the list:
here is the code:

```
<div id="about" class="row section">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2 style="color:black;">About me!</h2>
      <ul>
         <li >“If witnesses don't support the prosecution, what can the judge do? The judge is helpless. All this is unnecessary hype.</li>
         <li>“If witnesses don't support the prosecution, what can the judge do? The judge is helpless. All this is unnecessary hype.</li>
         <li>“If witnesses don't support the prosecution, what can the judge do? The judge is helpless. All this is unnecessary hype.</li>
         <li>“If witnesses don't support the prosecution, what can the judge do? The judge is helpless. All this is unnecessary hype.I</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   </ul>
   <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
      <img class="img-circle" src=" https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A "/>   
   </div>
</div>
<hr  style="border: 1px solid black"/>
```

Also i want this animation to happen when i click on the about section in the header!
here is the link to the code pen: https://codepen.io/saisree/full/WjVjMW/

Need some help! Also suggest on how this can be made improved more!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What animation do you want?

Comment: each item in the list should appear one by one with some time gap or any kind that suits the about section!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

You can simply apply animations on any element, With Delay as well  :

```
    <section class="wow slideInLeft"></section>
    <section class="wow slideInRight"></section>
    <section class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s">
    <section class="wow pulse" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="500ms">
```

Initiate : wow.init();

Demo : https://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/pen/yEJKn